# Displaying UIDocuments in Files App iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument, files-app

I'm trying to integrate my application with the Files App so that documents saved in my application are showed in the Files App, either under the 'iCloud Drive' or 'On My iPhone' folders. I've added the following keys the info.plist file:

```
UIFileSharingEnabled = true
LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = true
```

I'm also tried saving documents locally into the Documents folder and remotely into the iCloud. In both cases, documents are saved successfully and I can access them programatically from the app. But I am still unable to see a folder in the files app.

I've also noticed when saving local documents, they are being saved into a private directory, i.e:
`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/208C2D45-E1E2-4277-8824-0C54F4EA6CFA/Documents/Test.xyz/`

As opposed to the default documents directory:
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/208C2D45-E1E2-4277-8824-0C54F4EA6CFA/Documents/Test.xyz/`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using simulator or real device? I had the same problem on iOS 13.2 simulator.

Comment: I'm using a device.

Comment: I remember having a similar problem. Did you try changing your build or version number? From my experience, if you got the setup wrong once (for example forgetting the info.plist keys in the beginning), the whole build/version number is spoiled and you won‘t see the folder in Files. I would also try to programmatically erase the folder to achieve a reset

Comment: What is your code for saving the documents to the documents folder? More specifically, how are you getting a reference to your app's documents folder?